# Reverse Poco only Generating initial comment block

Tags: entity-framework, azure, efpocoadapter

I'm trying to generate models from an existing database using the Reverse POCO generator. I've not made any changes to the default template file and I've called my connection string "MyDbContext".

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xx.xxx.xx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ZooQ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ZooQDev;Password=******;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I've checked the credentials are ok by testing the connection in visual studio, so I know they are right. Only difference to the usual way I do this is that now I'm accessing a VM server on Azure, but I wouldn't think that would be the problem.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the generator, uninstalling and reinstalling Entity Framework, deleting and re-adding the template file and closing and re-opening Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Should be better at reporting errors, look at the generated database.cs file.

Comment: I am yeah (or at least I think I am) and there's only the initial comment block in the database.cs file